# How to call UIAlertviewController in NSObject Class in iOS9?

Tags: ios

Due to deprecation of alert view in iOS9 i’m facing difficulty  to show alert through NSObject class
because in UIAlertView there is one method to show alert [objaler show] ; but in iOS 9 to show alert 
we have to use presentViewController so anyone can tell me how to show alert view controller in nsobject class.

The code i want to called in NSObject class is as follow:

```
   UIAlertController *alert= [UIAlertController
                               alertControllerWithTitle:@"Login"
                               message:@"Enter your credentials here"
                               preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
                                                   //Do Some action here
                                               }];
    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                      NSLog(@"cancel btn");
                                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                                   }];
    [alert addAction:ok];
    [alert addAction:cancel];
   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

my question is i want to call that in NSObject class.
How to do that?

Comment: Why not try using NSNotification? On your NSObject class, post a notification then add an observer on the UIViewController class that will call a selector to show your UIAlertAction.

Comment: @JohnRusselUsi  Good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

Your ObjectClassName.h class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
+ (void)showAlertTitle:(NSString *)title withMessage:(NSString *)message onView:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

Your ObjectClassName.m Class

```
+ (void)showAlertTitle:(NSString *)title withMessage:(NSString *)message onView:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                  message:message
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* okButton = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                {
                                    //Handel your yes please button action here
                                    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                }];

    [alert addAction:okButton];

   [viewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

when You call import your Object Class :

```
#import "ObjectClassName.h";
[ObjectClassName showAlertTitle:@"Alert" withMessage:@"Alert Message" onView:self];
```

Comment: Well, the OP could simply push the view controller to alert controller if he has any available. This doesn't solve the point of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's the point – Apple tells you you probably SHOULDN'T do that.

The best you can do in this situation is to go through the view controllers' hierarchy (starting with `UIWindow`'s `-rootViewController`) and at least present it on a top-level controller.

The best you can do in general would be calling such alert in a proper view controller directly.

Comment: i know that we can't do that and also your's answer define that we have to go with the viewControllers Hierarchy so the your solution and mine are same and i'm defining the code and you wrote theoretically.

Comment: it's  a common sense that NSObject class has no UI so you can not do that thing. so please understanding the question and answer first.

Comment: I understood the question. The answer below is not a solution, it's just a wrapper of assigning view controller via method instead of assigning and calling it directly. Saves 2 lines of code, but the issue with finding the proper view controller to present still remains.

Answer (score 0):

your alert view is not called by the class method

```
+(void)initialize but by the instance -(id)init method
```

That is the reason why your instance doesn't get the notifications

the class method **"+(void)initialize"** is called when the class first load.

the instance method **"-(id)init"** has its name beginning by init, and is called when you create (instantiate) your object.

```
-(id)init { //alert view self = [super init]; return self; }
```